# Why is %ProgramFiles(x86)% returned without quotes?

Tags: windows-vista, environment-variables

Using this simple test batch script:

```
@echo off
echo %ProgramFiles%
echo %ProgramFiles(x86)%
```

is my output:

```
"C:\Program Files"
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

One variable is enclosed in quotes while the other isn't? Is this a bug of some sort, or a simple oversight on my behalf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange, I can't reproduce this on my machine (Windows Vista 64-bit SP 1). My output is

```
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

Are you sure you didn't insert quotes in your echo statement?

Comment: Hmm... I've rebooted since and now am getting the correct, expected result. I'm fairly positive that there were no quotes in my statements (as that was my first guess). I'll see if I can recreate the issue at all.

Comment: I'm blaming this one on "late night tinkering". I must have manually added quotes somewhere. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

On W2k8 x64 I get:

```
c:\temp>echo %ProgramFiles% & echo %ProgramFiles(x86)%
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

If you type "set" you can see what the environment variables are. I get:

```
c:\temp>set
...
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
...
```